# Using a transformer vs a voltage regulator

Tags: voltage-regulator

I have a 1hp belt sander that runs on 110 volts brought from the US.
Our power supply is 220 V.

Can I use a 4000 W SCR electronic voltage regulator instead of a transformer?

Voltage regulators are cheaper, smaller and lighter.

Comment: Please link the product details for the *4000 W SCR electronic voltage regulator*

Answer (score 1):

The transformer will be better.  The sander will get a good sinewave instead of a nasty chopped up trailing edge peaky waveform. The SCR regulator will make the motor run hotter and make more noise.

Comment: Could use double-conversion systems to solve the **nasty chopped up** part. But yes, I think the transformer is by far the better choice. They "just work right" and are simple enough. +1 despite the short answer.